# Adding Javascript Sly to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, slideshow

Is there a way to get "sly" (this javascript plugin: http://darsa.in/sly/) in a Wordpress site? I really like it but i can't find the way to put it in a wordpress site. Or maybe do you know something very similar?

Comment: Where do you want to put it? If there is a specific template Then would suggest to put it in the footer with the condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can download your script.js .Put your script.js into your js file of your theme folder  and then you can enqueue your js file like this:

```
function new_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_new_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/new_script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_new_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_scripts' );
```

You can read more here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/